# How to post process an xsl fo to add footnotes on second pass based on the page numbers?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an xml that I recive from the UI, that I use along with an xslfo to transform it to a pdf.

```
<tabs>
    <auth>
        <appointedBy>Test Person is a good SRC^1 boy</appointedBy>
        <country>Singapore</country>
        <name>NMRC</name>
    </auth>

    <meet>
        <minutes>These^2 are the minues and things like FFD^3 were discussed </minutes>
        <frequency>2</frequency>
        <responsibilities></responsibilities>
    </meet>

    
    <footnotes>
        <f1>SRC is a sales representative council</f1>
        <f2>PWF is the Prduct Workflow</f2>
        <f3>Borad of Reroad development</f4>
    </footnotes>

</tabs>
```

this is the xml, a corresponding xsl fo is present that simply displays this data in a table in a key value format.
After the first transformation is over, I generate an intermediate xsl fo, that represents the pdf, but in the fo format. I want to do a second pass on this intermediate xsl. so that I can add footnotes to the pdf based on the special characters present in the text. The footnotes should appear in the corresponding pages where that character appears. how do I achieve this? where ever ^1 is encountered in the intermediate, the pdf should have //footnotes/f1 in the footer and so on.
I have found no information on how to do this.
I have a couple of questions

0. Is this sort of second pass even possible with apache fop ?
   to add footnotes to corresponding pages based on where certain texts appear in the pdf.
1. what would the second pass xslt look like ? Because I want the original pdf to look the same, This second pass should just add footnotes to the original xsl fo.
2. During the second transformation, how do I send the xml data that actually has the corresponding footnotes? because in the transformer I can send the intermediate xsl fo and the new xsl fo to add the footnotes. I don't understand where the xml data can be sent.

Comment: I would post the current XSL so we can help you modify it. I see no reason for a two pass approach in the sample. One should be able to match when text contains the carret and add the appropriate footnote then.

Comment: @KevinBrown the reason I thought two pass approach was needed because different footnotes should be displayed on different pages. is something like this possible in the first pass itself?  I'll post the xslfo in some time

Comment: Footnote is a common FO element and will appear on the page in which it is referenced

Answer (score 0):

Obviously one way you could consider is to add the necessary XSLT code (e.g. templates) to process/generate the footnotes to your existing code and existing transformation (step); if you want several transformation steps then XSLT 1.0 allows that using variables and modes with the help of an extension function (usually exsl:node-set) to transform the variable values being result tree fragments back to node-sets for the next processing step or you can easily use XSLT 2 or 3 these days with Fop processing and Java by putting a recent version of Saxon HE (e.g. 10, 11, 12) on the classpath: in XSLT 2/3 you can have intermediary results of type node or node sequence, the (kind of) artificial type "result tree fragment" is gone and that way you would use e.g.

```
<xsl:import href="first-sheet.xsl"/>

<xsl:variable name="first-sheet-result">
  <xsl:apply-imports/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-sheet-result/node()" mode="step2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:mode name="step" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<!-- now make sure you have templates generating footnotes, might use a third mode, depending on the input (i.e. your intermediary FO) and the document structure) -->
```